# Change InertiaJS-Laravel default RootView

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am using `Laravel 8` and I have installed `InertiaJS`, but in my directory `resources/views/` I have a single file called `index.blade.php` which I plan to use with `InertiaJS`.

By default, `InertiaJS` looks for a file inside that directory called `app.blade.php`. I know writing the following statement:

`\Inertia\Inertia::setRootView('index');`

Change the `rootView` and allow me to use the file I have created. It may seem like a stupid question, but as far as I see it, I can do 2 things ..

- Rename file `index.blade.php` to `app.blade.php`
- Write the previous sentence .. in one of the `ServiceProviders` that I have

I wonder the following:

- `InertiaJS-Laravel` does not allow publishing a `ServiceProvider` with the command `php artisan vendor:publish`? *(the output of this command does not show me anything to publish regarding this package)*
- To solve my problem I should create a `ServiceProvider` like: `php artisan make:provider InertiaServiceProvider` and then register it?
- Or just add the previous statement to one of the `ServiceProvider` that already exist? Like in `app/Http/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

What do you recommend that would be better?

I want to seek the largest possible organization in my project. Thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update; after my initial answer (on 20-09-2020), Inertia [introduced middleware](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/releases/tag/v0.3.0) to handle your Inertia requests.

As described in the answers below, you can use the command `php artisan inertia:middleware` to generate this middleware. You can set the root index with:

```php
// Set root template via property
protected $rootView = 'app';

// OR
// Set root template via method
public function rootView(Request $request)
{
    return 'app';
}
```

You can find more info [in the docs](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup).

Answer (score 8):

Even tighter, just override the `rootView` method in `App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests` like this...

```
public function rootView(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->route()->getPrefix() == 'admin') {
       return 'layout.admin';
    }

    return parent::rootView($request);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this inside your controller on the fly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Inertia::setRootView('layouts.news');
        $users = User::all();

        return Inertia::render('News/Index', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no Idea what type of problem you are facing. But in this example I have tried to show how you can control your inertia root view from your controller.

Comment: This looks like the better approach for my use cases, where I want to have several pages. We already have routing in the route files; the middleware approach seems like it will create a shadow router there. But if you set the root in each controller action just before returning the view, that makes it just part of serving each route and keeps all your routing in one place.

Answer (score 5):

Replace in the `App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests`

```
protected $rootView = 'app';
```

with:

```
public function rootView(Request $request): string
{
    if ($request->route()->getPrefix() === '/admin') {
        return 'admin.app';
    }
    
    return 'app';
}
```

Comment: The `rootView` worked when the page refreshes. because the `HandleInertiaRequests` worked when the page refreshes and gets the master layout from the root! if after first load you change the page with ajax, the master blade layout not reloaded. if you need to change the master layout,  should create your master layout with vue and handle it with vue.

Comment: To do this, you need to work through the API and create master layers with vue.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be easier to change it in App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests.

Be sure to run `php artisan inertia:middleware` during inertia server-side installation.
Also include it in your web middleware group.

Then go to `App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests` and change the `$rootView` property to the name of the blade file you want to use. Example:

`protected $rootView = 'index';`

Answer (score 3):

**Extended @Olu Udeh answer**

overwrite handle method of `App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests` middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->route()->getPrefix() == 'admin'){
        $this->rootView = 'layouts.admin';
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 8 this work for me

```
App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests
```

Code

```
public function rootView(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->is('admin/*') or request()->is('admin'))
    {
        return 'admin';
    }

    return parent::rootView($request);
}
```