# Laravel 8, Jetstream, inertia: Looking for app in the DOM

Tags: javascript, laravel-8, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

OK, trying to move our Vuetify app to L8, Jetstream and the inertia stack.  I see this line in ./resources/js/app.js

```
const app = document.getElementById('app');
```

It's grabbing the app element in the DOM.
My question is --- what defined the app.

In my L7 app, it's defined in the single blade.php

```
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
```

I can't find it in L8 and this gets this....

```
initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"
```

Thanks, Jim in Florida

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613243/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  I was there a few days ago.

Comment: which blade.php is your L7 app pointing to? There is a possibility you would need to redefine the Inertia root view. In that case, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926485/change-inertiajs-laravel-default-rootview

Comment: OK, my web.php routes file contains:
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '^(?!nova).*$');
and that sends me to the spa.blade.php as I have 5 SPA routes defined in my routes.js file.  The spa.blade.php is shown in the first code example above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its defined by inertia `$rootView`

```
file: Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php

...
protected $rootView = 'app';
```

where 'app' means `app.blade.php` inside your view folder where you should have the `@inertia` directive